# Update a hidden input field with the name of an image on page load

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to update the value of a hidden input field called `id_0-instruction_task_one_image` with the file name of a particular image file when the page is loaded using java script and `<img onload="`

This is the script I am using to update the hidden field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateInput(ish) {  
    document.getElementById("id_0-instruction_task_one_image").value = ish;
    }  
</script>
```

This is the file path for the image, note I am also loading the file name into the `value` field:

```
<div class="image_rating">      
    <img src="{% static "survey/images/instruction_task_one/" %}{{display_image}}" value={{display_image}} onload="updateInput(this.value)"/>    
</div>
```

When I load the page the image is getting shown and the same file name is in the value field e.g. `value="ITI1.jpg"`

However the hidden form field does not update correctly and instead shows `value="undefined"` as below

```
<input id="id_0-instruction_task_one_image" name="0-instruction_task_one_image" type="hidden" value="undefined"/>
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been working on this for a while and I am convinced it should work. Thanks

Comment: are you using script at the bottom or top of the page?

Comment: The script is above the image

Comment: put the script at the bottom, just before the body tag closes

Comment: I tried it imidiatly after the image and I get the same result

Comment: If you're trying `this.value` and its returning a different value - in this case `undefined` - it means that the `this` isn't what you think it is when its being referenced. Check the scope of `this` bro

Comment: I also tried adding it to the bottom of the page, It does not even create the `value="undefined"` when I do that

Comment: press f12 key and goto console what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry it is not giving an error and it is showing `value="undefined"` when I have the script at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a problem with the way you're accessing and setting the html element attributes. Try using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` on the elements like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Set Attribute Value</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="image_rating">
    <img id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/JosephBazalgettePortrait.jpg/100px-JosephBazalgettePortrait.jpg"
    value="myValue" onload="updateInput(this)" />
  </div>

  <input id="id_0-instruction_task_one_image" name="0-instruction_task_one_image" type="hidden"
  value="undefined" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateInput(ish) {
      var valueAttribute = ish.getAttribute("value");
      document.getElementById("id_0-instruction_task_one_image").setAttribute(
        "value", valueAttribute);
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I was using a very similar script to update another hidden field but the value in that case was being generated by a jQuery sliderbar and would have been constantly updated after teh page was loaded. Thanks for your help